# How do I control parskip within a tcolorbox?

Tags: spacing, tcolorbox, parskip

I am using the [`tcolorbox`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tcolorbox) to provide some beautiful frames around certain parts of my document; I use the [`parskip`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/parskip) to give nice spacing between paragraphs.

When I have more than one paragraph inside a `tcolorbox` the `parskip` is not obeyed, as highlighted in the screen shot below. I have searched the manual, but it *seems* to describe before and after skips, but not '*during*'. How can this be fixed?

[image: screenshot]

Here's a complete MWE that demonstrates the problem:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just in case. If you use KOMA-Script classes, you just need to add `\KOMAoptions{parskip = half-}` inside the `tcolorbox` environment.

Comment: Don't set `\parskip`, it's easier. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg could you elaborate? do you recommend against the `parskip` package?

Comment: I recommend against using a nonzero parskip, which is useful only for commercial letters, in my opinion.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, there is a native `tcolorbox` solution. The content of a `tcolorbox` is processed with the typical settings of `parbox` and `minipage`. You can switch this kind processing by setting `parbox=false` to do a mimicry of 'normal' processing.

You find this in the `tcolorbox` documentation  as **Text Characteristics** ([4.18 Text Characteristics on p. 98, for current `tcolorbox` version 4.22 [2019/11/15]](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf#page=98)).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[parbox=false]
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much :) Sorry I missed this in the documentation :) I love your package, thanks so much for all of the work that you have done :)

Comment: I also missed that option in the documentation; fortunately we have you here :-)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina My subsection title **Text Characteristics** may also be better chosen ... ;-)

Comment: +1: Just what I needed!

Comment: If I use `parbox=false`, it doesn't work to put the environment first in an enumerate item, because then the left side of the box will cut into the item number. Is it possible to move indent the left side of the box (move it to the right) without also moving the number? I've tried using `enlarge left by=1cm`, but then the number is also moved.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, I was building the same MWE before stackoverflowing this issue :D

Answer (score 9):

One option would be to use the settings from `parskip` inside a new environment defined using `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parskip}

\newenvironment{mycolorbox}[1][]
  {\if\detokenize{#1}\relax\relax
      \begin{tcolorbox}
    \else
      \begin{tcolorbox}[#1]
    \fi
  \parskip=0.5\baselineskip \advance\parskip by 0pt plus 2pt
  \parindent=0pt
}
  {\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mycolorbox}
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]
\end{mycolorbox}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]