# How to create a blank line between lines without using \\

Tags: line-breaking

In my tex document I have an ungodly amount of \\ from when I first started writing tex files. (~5000 in total)

Right now I am trying to delete all of them. I want to just have a blank line between two lines when I create a blink line in the unpublished tex file. Right now I have to hit \\ in order to create a blank line between them.

For example:

**Right now:**

In tex

> ABC
>
> DEF

In pdf

> ABC
>   DEF

**When I really want:**

In tex

> ABC
>
> DEF

In pdf

> ABC
>
> DEF

Is there something to put in the preamble to make this happen?

Thanks

Comment: A blank line between paragraphs starts a new one. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Now I'm confused. Do you want paragraphs to be marked by a vertical space instead of indentation?

Comment: Why do you want space between them in the first place? It makes the text artificially longer. And if this text also have a lot of math, relying on blank lines to mark new paragraphs, create a lot of potential for confusing communication. So, do you really need it?

Comment: `\usepackage{parskip}` (documentation: http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/macros/latex/contrib/parskip/parskip-doc.pdf) or if you don't like packages: `\parskip=<dimension> \parindent=0pt`?

Comment: @daleif I want to create something like: Concept 1 "...." , blank line, Concept 2 "....". Right now I am making this happen by inserting \\ after Concept 1 "...".  whereas  I would rather just have a blank line instead of having \\

Comment: What are the concepts? Why do you have 5000 of them? Is have a hard look at what exactly this is, and if there is a better syntax or markup to provide this.

Comment: Just keep a blank line when you want a new paragraph (which is different from a new line). Later you can set up the vertical space for new paragraphs.

Comment: It sounds like `Concept 1` should be a list item (eg description list) or a sub*section heading. Certainly you don't want `\\ ` But to answer the original question `parskip` package is what you are looking for. but `Concept 1` on its own isn't really a paragraph

Comment: @1010011010 Hey that worked thanks a lot, but parskip is not affecting the texts in a tcoloredbox, do you have solution for that as well or is it too much to ask?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I agree but right now the tex document is too broken to be fixed. It is beyond help. But at least I could remove some \\ so whoever takes it over won't have an heart attack because I saw his tex and there were no \\ or \newline LOL.

Comment: @IllegalImmigrant http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154901/how-do-i-control-parskip-within-a-tcolorbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
\documentclass{article}
% set space between paragraphs
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5cm}
% set indents for paragraphs
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0mm}
\begin{document}
    ABC

    DEF \vspace{2cm} % use vspace (vertical space) when a different spacing is needed.

    GHI
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks I applied this solution but it does not seem to affect the linespacing within {tcolorbox} do you know if there is a fix for that?