# tcolorbox: parbox=false AND hyphenationfix=true

Tags: spacing, tcolorbox, parskip

1. I want the text in a `{tcolorbox}` to exhibit the same paragraph style as the main body. As far as I know (as per the first reference) this requires using `\RestoreParskip`:

   ```
   \newcommand*{\RestoreParskip}{%
     \setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}%
     \setlength{\parindent}{\currentparindent}%
   }%
   ```

   where `\currentparskip` and `\currentparindent` needs to be initialized *before* the `{tcolorbox}`.

   From the documentation, this appears to be exactly what `parbox=false` is intended to do:

   > If the key value is set to false, the normal main text behavior is restored.

   *However*, this feature is marked as experiemntal as of 2015-10-14 with the caveat:

   > In some situations, this has some unwanted side effects. It is recommended that you use this experimental setting only where you really want to have this feature.

   As I defintely want the same paragraph spacing inside `{tcolorbox}`, it seems I should use this.
2. Secondly, using `hyphenationfix=true` seems to be useful:

   > Long words at the beginning of paragraphs in very narrow boxes will not be hyphenated using pdflatex. This problem is circumvented by applying the hyphenationfix option.

   However, there is a warning:

   [image]

---

Using the example text given in the documentation, one can see that `parbox=false, hyphenationfix=true` together don't seem to work (see 3. in the output of the MWE).  I can fix this by leaving `parbox=true` using `\RestoreParskip` manually (see 4).

Results without `{parskip}` and with `{parskip}`:

[image]
[image]

### Questions:

1. What else is `parbox=false` doing (besides the `\RestoreParskip` functionality) that causes it to fail with `hyphenationfix=true`?
2. What functionality am I losing by manually using `\RestoreParskip`?
3. When will `parbox=false` functionality leave the experimental designation? I realize that this particluar question can only be answered by the package author, but as I have experienced the pain of having experimental features removed, it would be good to know if this is still really experimental or just that the documentation has not been updated.

### Notes:

- For now, I do *not* require `breakable=true`, but might need it in the future. In case it is relevant, comments addressing these cases separately would be useful.

### References:

- [How to preserve the same parskip in minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43002/4301).
- [How do I control parskip within a tcolorbox?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154901/4301).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[textwidth=4cm]{geometry}

%\usepackage{parskip}% Needs to also work with parskip

\newlength{\currentparskip}
\newlength{\currentparindent}
\setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}
\setlength{\currentparindent}{\parindent}

\newcommand*{\RestoreParskip}{%
    \setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}%
    \setlength{\parindent}{\currentparindent}%
}%

\newcommand*{\Mytext}{%
    Rechnungsadjunktentochter.\par
    Statthaltereikonzipist.
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title={1. Default}]
    \Mytext
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[hyphenationfix, title={2. hyphenationfix}]
    \Mytext
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[hyphenationfix, parbox=false, title={3. hyphenationfix, parbox=false}]
    \Mytext
\end{tcolorbox}

\setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    hyphenationfix, 
    before upper=\RestoreParskip\noindent,
    title={4. hyphenationfix, \texttt{\string\RestoreParskip}},
    ]
    \Mytext
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Definitely nice example words :)

Comment: @TeXnician: :-) I assumed if the words were good enough for the documentation, then they were good enough for a question.

Answer (score 4):

`parbox=false` works quite differently to your `\RestoreParskip`: it doesn't reset two length, but replace the call to `\@parboxrestore` which would do this

```
\let\if@nobreak\iffalse
\let\if@noskipsec\iffalse
\let\par\@@par
\let\-\@dischyph
\let\'\@acci\let\`\@accii\let\=\@acciii
\parindent\z@ \parskip\z@skip
\everypar{}%
\linewidth\hsize
\@totalleftmargin\z@
\leftskip\z@skip \rightskip\z@skip \@rightskip\z@skip
\parfillskip\@flushglue
\lineskip\normallineskip
\lineskiplimit\normallineskiplimit
\baselineskip\normalbaselineskip
\sloppy
\let\\\@normalcr
```

by this

```
 \noindent%
 \linewidth\hsize%
 \@totalleftmargin\z@%
 \leftskip\z@skip%
 \rightskip\z@skip%
 \@rightskip\z@skip%
```

1. Important for your first question is the additionally `\noindent`: It should suppress the indent in the first line but means that the paragraph has already started before the `hyphenationfix` can kick in (which uses a `\everypar` trick). So add a `\hspace{0pt}` yourself for the first paragraph.
2. The main difference is that with your `\RestoreParskip`, `\sloppy` is active. 
   The other settings from the standard `\@parboxrestore` could be relevant in some cases, but I didn't analyze them.

Comment: What activates `\sloppy` in this case?

Comment: The default \@parboxrestore contains \sloppy.